# Magento system log errors that I cannot get rid off

Tags: php, magento

I'm having two problems in my system.log that I'm having some problems resolving. The site seems to run fine, but I would very much like to remove these ongoing errors from the log.

---

> **Notice**: Undefined variable: order  in /var/www/... on line 17

```
// line 17
$merchantnumber = $standard->getConfigData('merchantnumber', $order ? $order->getStoreId() : null);
```

---

> **Warning**: Division by zero  in /var/www/... on line 267

```
// line 267
"vat" => (float)round((string)((round($order->getBaseShippingInclTax(),2)-round($order->getBaseShippingAmount(),2))/round((string)$order->getBaseShippingAmount(),2))*100, 2)
```

---

**UPDATE**

```
// line 258-281 
                $items = $order->getAllItems();
    foreach ($items as $itemId => $item)
    {
        $invoice["lines"][] = array
        (
            "id" => $item->getSku(),
            "description" => $item->getName(),
            "quantity" => round($item->getQtyOrdered(), 0),
            "price" => $item->getBasePrice()*100,
            "vat" => (float)round((string)((round($item->getBasePriceInclTax(),2)-round($item->getBasePrice(),2))/round((string)$item->getBasePrice(),2))*100, 2)
        );
    }

    $invoice["lines"][] = array
    (
        "id" => $order->getShippingMethod(),
        "description" => $order->getShippingDescription(),
        "quantity" => 1,
        "price" => $order->getBaseShippingAmount()*100,
        "vat" => (float)round((string)((round($order->getBaseShippingInclTax(),2)-round($order->getBaseShippingAmount(),2))/round((string)$order->getBaseShippingAmount(),2))*100, 2)
    );

    return json_encode($invoice);
}
```

*I've posted the wrong code before sorry, I was confused when looking throug the errorlog because the same (Devider) error appeared on both the Item and Order part.*

Comment: Your two snippets of code don't match on line 267. One refers to `$order->...` and the 258-269 one refers to `$item->...`. Which makes sense if some items are be VAT-exempt, and others aren't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Magento code seems to often rely on PHP's tolerance for *logic* errors which are considered *notices*.

```
 $merchantnumber = $standard->getConfigData('merchantnumber', $order ?
   $order->getStoreId() : null);
```

If `$order` is not set we want to use NULL instead of the order's store Id:

```
 $merchantnumber = $standard->getConfigData('merchantnumber',
   isset($order) ? $order->getStoreId() : null);
```

In the second file:

**UPDATE** check out if you're referring to `$order` or `$item`. If it's in a loop, it is probably the latter.

```
"vat" => (float)round((string)((round($item->getBaseShippingInclTax(),2)-round($item->getBaseShippingAmount(),2))/round((string)$item->getBaseShippingAmount(),2))*100, 2)
```

the VAT% is back-calculated from ShippingInclTax (which is ShippingAmount + VAT). Only, if getBaseShippingAmount() is zero, the calculation crashes.

To cope with that we ought to have:

```
 'vat' => (0 == round($item->getBaseShippingAmount(),2)) ? 0 :
          (float)round((string)(
 (round($item->getBaseShippingInclTax(),2)
 -round($item->getBaseShippingAmount (),2)
 )/round((string)$item->getBaseShippingAmount(),2)
 )*100,2),
```

...I'm not really happy with all those `round`s, but they probably are there so that printed accounts "check" up to the last decimal and avoid strange results such as 10.33 + 10.33 + 9.33 = 30.00 instead of 29.99.

I would write

```
 'vat' => (0 == $item->getBaseShippingAmount()) ? 0
        : round(
             100.0*(
               $item->getBaseShippingInclTax()/$item->getBaseShippingAmount()
               -1.0
             )
          ,2),
```

but even if it is mathematically more sound, I'm afraid that the results might not "match" with what Magento prints elsewhere.

If you're using `$order` in a loop (meaning you've got the same value whatever the item), you'd be better advised in calculating VAT before the loop and then use it inside.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth answer, It's making alot of sense. I'll definitley try out some of your suggestions and see if I can make the errors disappear!

Comment: I got back to the error log and spotted that the same kind of error on both the $item and $order piece of the code

Comment: Ah, I see. So my code is correct if you put $order in it; for $item you also have to change the function names. Both code sections need correcting, though.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case you can try changing that line to

```
$merchantnumber = $standard->getConfigData('merchantnumber', (isset($order) && $order) ? $order->getStoreId() : null);
```

In the second case I cannot tell exactly what value should go to `"vat"` in case when `$order->getBaseShippingAmount()` is 0. I suspect you need to do something like

```
if (!$order->getBaseShippingAmount()) {
   return;
}
```

to be added somewhere above line 267, but it's hard to tell for sure without seeing the code.

Comment: `!empty($order)` is semantically identical to `(isset($order) && $order)` and will still remove the error

Answer (score 1):

**A notice is not an error**. You can either choose to ignore it, or you can check if the `order` variable exists using `isset`:

```
 ...er', isset($order) ? $...
```

**Division by zero should always be avoided** because the answer is usually undefined (it is mathematically undefined at least). Check that the denominator is not zero *before* you try to do the division.

Comment: `You can either choose to ignore it, or...` - I would always go with "or ...". A notice *is* an error, it's just a non-fatal one. Always fix everything that triggers errors, no matter the severity.

Comment: DaveRandom, I do not entirely agree. A notice is just that: a notice! It is a warning that you are doing something that may not be intended. In this case it looks like they check if `$order` is set by trying if it evaluates to `true`, an operation that have a fairly well-defined behavior in PHP. Notices are thrown to make it easier to track down hard-to-find bugs but this does not look like a bug and so can possibly be ignored. I personally hate to work with stuff I'm not sure about what it is (thus trying to avoid PHP altogether) but here they actually *check* the variable before using it.

Comment: Here's definition of Notice from PHP itself: `E_NOTICE - run-time notices (these are warnings which often result from a bug in your code, but it's possible that it was intentional (e.g., using an uninitialized variable and relying on the fact it's automatically initialized to an empty string)` The fact that `E_NOTICE` is an error-reporting level should speak for itself. A notice **is** an error, just with low priority. And you should avoid any kind of errors

Comment: Slayer, the quote you used is on my side, though. It indeed says it's a warning (not an error) and that the use may be intentional (and therefore have expected behavior. I don't understand why we have this discussion as I clearly gave two different valid solutions, of which one can choose according to taste or religion.